# how to syntax highlight HTML codes entered by users in a text area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a tutorial application where users can type in their HTML/Javascript/CSS codes inside a text area, after entering the codes they will hit a button called "render". on button click, the user-entered code will be rendered inside a div.

the application is itself written in HTML5 and Javascript.

The problem is when users type their codes inside the text area, it comes in plane text/or as per the text property of the text area (if I set it via CSS).

Is there any way to provide a syntax highlighting feature in my text area (which is common in many text editors including visual studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) would do this for you and is excellent. It has an [HTML mode](http://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html).

Comment: Thank you Tim and everyone. The codemirror link helped a lot :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [ecoder](http://ecoder.quintalinda.com/)?

Which is based on [EditArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/?page=editArea) (see [live examples](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/exemples/exemple_full.html)).

Comment: Thanks Jared, I'll download the ecoder source and look into it to find out a way to implement the feature.

Comment: EditArea is really more like what you're looking for. Checkout the examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little heavyweight, but [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/) is a pretty remarkable project that does what you're asking for and more. Try out the [kitchen sink demo](http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html) to get a feel for it, but it can take pretty much any textarea and make a full-fledged text editor out of it.

[Mozilla tri-licensed Mozilla (MPL/GPL/LGPL) code on GitHub](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace)

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult project to do from scratch, which is why there are tools out there that already do this.

You can see some tools here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor

Most of these are open source, so you can add in functions pretty easily to make it work the way that you'd like.